# Change Session Table Name and Customize Django Session Table

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-sessions

**My problem:**

I'm trying to change the Django session table name from "`django_session`" to some other name as "`User_session`"

**What I tried:**

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
Session._meta.db_table = "my_session"
```

I placed the above code in Project's `__init__.py` file. But I'm getting error as calling session before the Session middleware has been initialized.

**What I want:**

I need to change the `django_session` table name to some other table name and add few columns to that table. And especially, where to place the code in the Django project(This is more important).

**NOTE:**

I'm using `Django 2.1.11 and Python 3.7`

Kindly help me to get rid off this problem.

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this? The session implementation is internal to Django, you shouldn't change it.

Comment: I'll explain the exact scenario. I have a database with already created django_session table for different application. Now, we have another application where it requires django_session with extra fields inside it. Now, I shouldn't use the existing django_session table and should not modify it. I should create my own table for Session and need to store and access the Session data

Answer (score 0):

you can change your session model in your python/env site-packages django/contrib/session/models and change your table name

Comment: This should be used as a last resort. If we start customizing to the code in site-packages, we have to distribute them together with the project source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give a custom name or create a custom field in the session table, you can follow the following step.

Define a custom session backend:

```
my_project
    my_project/
        settings.py
        session_backend.py
        ...
    user/
        models.py
        ...
```

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore as DBStore
import user


class SessionStore(DBStore):

    @classmethod
    def get_model_class(cls):
        return user.models.MySession

    def create_model_instance(self, data):
        """
        overriding the function to save the changes to db using `session["user_id"] = user.id` .
        This will create the model instance with the custom field values. 
        When you add more field to the custom session model you have to update the function 
        to handle those fields as well.
        """
        obj = super().create_model_instance(data)
        try:
            user_id = data.get('user_id')
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            user_id = None

        obj.user_id = user_id
        return obj
```

then in `setting.py` import your custom class

```py
SESSION_ENGINE = "my_project.session_backend"
```

Define the custom model in `models.py` in the app say `user`

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session


class MySession(Session):
    # you can also add custom field if required like this user column which can be the FK to the user table 
    user = models.ForeignKey('user', on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    class Meta:
        app_label = "user"
        db_table = "my_session"
```

now run the following commands for migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Done :)

Comment: Custom session table is not created. How to tell django to create the session table in the migrations

Comment: if you define the model correctly then running the migration will create the table

Comment: I can't create more apps in my project and if I try to run this with the apps I already have, I get the error that the user model referrenced as the foreign key in MySession is missing.